# How can I get the count of how many times a string appears in my list?

Tags: string-manipulation, counting

I have a list of strings, like so:

```
{"aa bb", "cc dd", "aa bb", "aa bb", "cc dd", "ww ss", "ss ss", "kk mm"}
```

I know `WordCounts` will return the numbers of every single word, but I want to the word group numbers, i.e., "aa bb" 3 times, and "cc dd" 2 times. How can I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try `Tally`

```
lst = {"aa bb", "cc dd", "aa bb", "aa bb", "cc dd", "ww ss", "ss ss",   "kk mm"};
Tally[lst]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Edit by m_goldberg

As J.M. says in his comment below, `Counts` will give the same information as an association.

```
Counts[data]
```

> `<|"aa bb" -> 3, "cc dd" -> 2, "ww ss" -> 1, "ss ss" -> 1, "kk mm" -> 1|>`

This is equivalent to

```
Rule @@@ Tally[data] // Association
```

Comment: `Counts[]` should also work.